# Problem with casewise list in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, spss

I am using binary logistic regression to test this model:

$\text{logit}(\rho_1) = \alpha + \beta_1(\text{INDDIR}) + \beta_2(\text{INDCHAIR}) + \beta_3(\text{BOARDSIZE}) +\\ \beta_4(\text{DIRSHIP}) + \beta_5(\text{MEETING}) + \beta_6(\text{EXPERT}) + \beta_7(\text{INSTI}) +\\ \beta_8(\text{DEBT}) + \beta_9(\text{LnSIZE}) + \beta_{10}(\text{BIG4})$

I have some doubt on the casewise list (outliers). The first time I run the analysis, there were 44 outliers. I deleted all these 44 cases. Then, I re-run the analysis. Again, 11 outliers were appeared. I deleted all these 11 cases then re-run. Again and again, 6 outliers were found!

So, should I delete all outliers or it would be a never ending story?

Comment: @lcl23 Listwise deletion is usually for subjects with missing data on any one of the covariates. Could you indicate how you define an outlier in your particular case?

Comment: Google leads me to believe `casewise` may be some 'feature' of SPSS. Not a package I've ever used, unfortunately(?)

Comment: Hi chl, casewise list is a table produced for analysis of residual in logistic regression, nothing related to missing data. i learnt from this link: http://www.uk.sagepub.com/burns/website%20material/Chapter%2024%20-%20Logistic%20regression.pdf. Page 17.

Comment: @lcl23 Ok, I just browsed the attached doc; p. 583, it is said: "the casewise list produces a list of cases that didn’t fit the model well." (where outlying criterion is considered by default to be individuals outside a 2 SD band, p. 577). So why did you run so many instances of your logistic regression? Did you first look at the 44 individuals that were flagged when fitting the initial model?

Comment: @lcl23 This procedure will likely converge, but the results might be useless.  Exactly what do they characterize?  Certainly not the population or process you are trying to understand, because you have thrown away so much of the data!  A solution developed specifically for this phenomenon is *robust regression,* which automatically downweights--but does not eliminate--unusual cases.

Comment: @ICI23 and whuber - I'm going to look up robust regression.  But one question is, 44 out of how many?  If out of 50,000, then I would feel less squeamish about excluding at least that first set of influential or poorly-fitting cases.  Beyond that,  normally (and forgive me if this is basic stuff you already know) you'd want to examine all your distributions and see whether some outliers are actually implausible values, like age being coded as 999 for 'missing.'  Also you'd often want to transform any very skewed distribution to pull outliers in.

Comment: @chl & rolando2 - 44 out of 797. All ZResid > 2.58, so i deleted all 44 cases & re-run. As mentioned, still appear 11 outliers. By the way, I thought logistic doesn't require normal distribution?